Vertically align middle of image to full x-height of font
CSS has a vertical-align: middle property for inline elements, which vertically aligns the middle of the element to half of the x-height of the parent element's font. However, this often puts images a little lower than I want them. Is there a way to vertically align the middle of an arbitrary image to the full x-height of the parent element's font?
For instance, setting vertical-align: calc(1ex - 50%) on the image doesn't work because it takes 50% of the parent element's height rather than 50% of the image's height.
Actual output from vertical-align: middle using the image :


img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
<p>This is some text with an <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/fPdDaN6t.png"> image</p>



Image of output:

Desired output:


Is there any other constrain (such as image's height) known beforehand in your use case? It might possibly help. Otherwise I assume you are seeking universal solution for images of any height inside text of any size and metric, what, to my current knowledge, really does not exist in robust and cross-browser consistent manner, sadly. (Centring some things relative to other things is still hard in CSS.)

have you tried giving margin and padding zero(cause by default some elements have) try using inspect of your browsers console.

It seems that adding transform: translatey(-0.5ex); to the vertical-align: middle; does the trick to some degree:


img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: translatey(-0.5ex);
  width: 20px; /* unrelated */
}

body {
  font-size: 22px;
}
<span style="font-family: serif; word-spacing: -.5ch;">
x <img height="10" src="https://i.sstatic.net/fPdDaN6t.png">
x <img height="40" src="https://i.sstatic.net/fPdDaN6t.png">
x <img height="80" src="https://i.sstatic.net/fPdDaN6t.png">
x <img height="120" src="https://i.sstatic.net/fPdDaN6t.png">
x
</span>

<span style="font-family: Impact; word-spacing: -.3ch;">
x <img height="10" src="https://i.sstatic.net/fPdDaN6t.png">
x <img height="40" src="https://i.sstatic.net/fPdDaN6t.png">
x <img height="80" src="https://i.sstatic.net/fPdDaN6t.png">
x <img height="120" src="https://i.sstatic.net/fPdDaN6t.png">
x
</span>
<span style="font-family: monospace; word-spacing: -1ch;">
x <img height="10" src="https://i.sstatic.net/fPdDaN6t.png">
x <img height="40" src="https://i.sstatic.net/fPdDaN6t.png">
x <img height="80" src="https://i.sstatic.net/fPdDaN6t.png">
x <img height="120" src="https://i.sstatic.net/fPdDaN6t.png">
x
</span>



Presumably, this workaround will fail miserably for fonts with disproportionally tall descenders and narrow cap height with resulting baseline shifted unusually high in the line box. (Cannot find a good example right now, maybe in CSS the x-height "band" is always centred after all (?))

This actually works quite well.  If you have multiple lines, this will cause the images to be 0.5ex too high, but you can solve that by adding margin-top: 0.5ex; margin-bottom: -0.5ex; to the image.

@v-rob Hm, don't see that wrapped line misplaces the image, but it is true it leaves the .5ex extra gap on the bottom of computed line box with the image, and sticks the image probably too close to previous line, potentially even covering descenders. Honestly don't know RN how to amend that. But contrary to get the  image not affect line box at all and leak over/under adjacent lines, it seems to be possible to ditch the transform and replace it with sth like margin-top: calc(-101ex); margin-bottom: calc(-100ex);, based on your idea with margins. What exactly is your intended outcome?

The image being too close to the previous line (and too far away from the following line) was what I was talking about--sorry for not being clear.  Adding the margins fixes that problem.  For instance, https://jsfiddle.net/k948p1qo/10/

Yes, it does ameliorate spacing of the second image in your Fiddle, but if I see correctly also pushes the centre of the image back below x-height cap (looking at Edge and Firefox).

Wow, I'm embarrassed that I didn't notice that. I suppose that defeats the whole purpose :)  I guess translateY() on its own is the best solution we have for now.
